# ElasticSearch JDBC River Is Not Fetching All Records From MSSQL

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have setup an ElasticSearch river with 20 minutes interval. Here is the river definition:

```
 {
    "type": "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=DBName",
        "user": "user",
        "password": "pass",
        "sql": "select * from table",
        "index": "indexname",
        "type": "typename",
        "autocommit": true,
        "strategy": "simple",
        "schedule": "0 0/20 * 1/1 * ? *"
    }
}
```

River is executing successfully with 20 minutes interval. But when river executes **it only runs for 3 minutes and does not fetch all records**. I have around 3.3 Million records in my table and on every execution of river it fetches around 0.3-0.5 million records (in 3 minutes) and then stopped.

My question is why river stops after 3 minutes? River still has 17 more minutes from its next run, it should execute for next 17 minutes or until all records are fetched.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Note: I am checking river status from BigDesk and "status" flag which sets to true when river starts execution.

Comment: What is the size of your data? How much RAM are you giving to elasticsearch?

Comment: My server specs are: 
2 Cores CPU
2 GB RAM
40GB HardDisk

I am using 3 separate VPS for data clustering. All having same specs and running only ElasticSearch on them. They are CentOS VPS.

Comment: @SaadKhan Then use that, don't invent new words; I have edited your post to use minutes.

Comment: So what is the size of the data byte wise?

Comment: Size of data is: 186MB (190192 KB to be exact)

Comment: Scheduling the river every minutes doesn't mean that the river will run for 20 minutes. It means that each 20 minutes elasticsearch will try to fetch data from the database applying the rules that you define in the river

Comment: I understand that. But When river runs for 3 minutes it fetches around 0.3 million records and then on the next run river fetches next 0.3 million records. Because of this behaviour I have to wait for minimum 5 runs of River then my 1.5 million records will be fetched. 
Why it does not fetch all 1.5 million records in one run?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated